# Vuejs 2 with Laravel 5.4 backend, post (Unauthorized) error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm learning Vuejs 2, and building a customer directory app for fun and testing, Laravel 5.4 as backend (api) with Cors and Passport packages. and Vuejs as a frontend with vue-router and axios I'm able to login and store the token in a cookie I get the all the customers without any errors, but when I try to create a new customer I get the following errors in console **POST http://localhost:8000/api/customer 401 (Unauthorized)** in network **{"error":"Unauthenticated."}**. if I comment the auth:api middleware I can post without any errors.

**routes/api.php**

```
      Route::get('/', 'CustomerCtrl@index');
   Route::get('customer/{id}', 'CustomerCtrl@show');
Route::post('customer', 'CustomerCtrl@store');
Route::delete('customer/{id}', 'CustomerCtrl@destroy');
Route::put('customer/{id}', 'CustomerCtrl@update');
```

**CustomerCtrl.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Customer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomerCtrl extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return response()->json(Customer::all(), 200);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        return response()->json(Customer::findOrFail($id), 200);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
          'first_name' => 'required',
          'last_name' => 'required',
          'email' => 'required|email',
          'phone' => 'required',
          'address' => 'required',
          'country' => 'required',
        ]);
        Customer::create($request->all());
        return response()->json('Customer Created', 200);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
          'first_name' => 'required',
          'last_name' => 'required',
          'email' => 'required|email',
          'phone' => 'required',
          'address' => 'required',
          'country' => 'required',
        ]);
        $customer = Customer::findOrFail($id);
        $customer->update($request->all());
        return response()->json('Customer Updated', 200);
    }

    public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $customer = Customer::findOrFail($id);
        $customer->forceDelete();
        return response()->json('Customer Deleted', 200);
    }
}
```

**new customer component (vuejs)**

```
<template>
<div class="add-customer">
  <h1 class="page-header">Add Customer</h1>
  <div v-if="isErrors" class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="error in errors">
        {{error[0]}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <form @submit.prevent>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstName" v-model="first_name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lastName" v-model="last_name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" v-model="email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Phone">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" id="Phone" v-model="phone" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="country">Country</label>
      <input type="text" id="country" v-model="country" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="address">Adress</label>
      <textarea type="text" id="address" v-model="address" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button @click.prevent="addCustomer" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'add-customer',
  data() {
    return {
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      address: '',
      phone: '',
      country: '',
      email: '',
      errors: {},
      isErrors: false
    }
  },
  head: {
    title: {
      inner: 'Add Customer'
    },
  },
  methods: {
    addCustomer() {
      this.$http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/customer', {
        headers: {
           'Authorization':'Bearer ' + this.$cookie.get('token')
        },
        first_name: this.first_name,
        last_name: this.last_name,
        address: this.address,
        phone: this.phone,
        country: this.country,
        email: this.email
      }).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'Customers'
        })
      }).catch(res => {
        this.isErrors = true;
        this.errors = res.response.data;
        console.log(res);

      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

**Login.vue component**

```
  methods: {
    login() {
      const data = {
        client_id: 4,
        client_secret: '55bC4Ud1ariLqnHSk1fxKiKHF8FDI8NTWHR5d13k',
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: this.email,
        password: this.password

      }
      this.$http.post('http://localhost:8000/oauth/token/', data).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.$cookie.set('api_token', res.data.access_token, 1);
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'Customers'
        })
      }).catch(res => {
        this.isErrors = true;
        this.errors = res.response.data;
        console.log(res);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved :) by defining default axios baseurl and headers in main.js (Vue).

**main.js**

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000/api';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + 
VueCookie.get('api_token');
```

and removed all locally defined headers in all components.

Comment: What should I do when deploying an application to a hosting? with `axios` call to `htt://localhost:8000/`? Should I change a link or smth like this?

Comment: @КамиловТимур Yes, you should change the link. use [donenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) for different environments.

Comment: I use `Laravel 5.4` on my backend and `MySQL` as a database. How should I change an API link?

Answer (score 1):

Use xsrf tokens or Add the following to `api/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
protected $except = [
    'customer',
    'customer/*'
    'customer/*'
];
```

This will disable xsrf tokens. Please use with caution.

Comment: I don't think this implementation is right, it works only because you removed all CSRF token validation for that route, which in turn opens OPs code for XSS which in turn, if his next POST request would be a file upload, a not $user's own upload, in avatars that would be a nuisance, but on more important stuff, say crypto coins app, that would be horrendous.

Comment: @clusterBuddy You're 110% right. It's not the preferred way of doing things. It's best to use the XSRF tokens.